# How to pass the multiple Query Parameters in url using unirest in the nodejs

Tags: node.js, rest, api, unirest

In NodeJS using Unirest http library i am automating the Rest Apis. Currently i am stuck on how to pass the query parameters with rest url.

i have tried following solutions but non is working: solution 1

```
unirest('GET', 'https://my-domain.com/Api/learner/courses')
.header({
        "content-type": "application/json",
        "authorization": token
    })
.queryString("pageNumber", "1")
.queryString("sortDirection", "ASC")
.queryString("status", "all")
.end(function (response) {
response.status.should.be.equal(200);
});
```

got the following error on above execution:

```
TypeError: unirest(...).header(...).queryString is not a function
```

solution 2:

```
unirest('GET', 'https://my-domain.com/Api/learner/courses{pageNumber}{sortDirection}{status}')
.header({
        "content-type": "application/json",
        "authorization": token
    })
.routeParam("pageNumber", "1")
.routeParam("sortDirection", "ASC")
.routeParam("status", "all")
.end(function (response) {
response.status.should.be.equal(200);
});
```

got error:

```
TypeError: unirest(...).header(...).routeParam is not a function
```

solution 3:

```
const param = {
        pageNumber: 1,
        sortDirection: "ASC",
        status: "all"}
```

unirest('GET', 'https://my-domain.com/Api/learner/courses{pageNumber}{sortDirection}{status}')
    .header({
            "content-type": "application/json",
            "authorization": token
        })
    .send(param)
    .end(function (response) {
    response.status.should.be.equal(200);
    });

got error:

```
Uncaught Error: Error: got 500 response
```

Any help would be much appriciated! thanks.

Answer (score 1):

queryString is not a method defined in unirest it is query.

See here [unirest npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/unirest)

```
unirest('GET', 'https://my-domain.com/Api/learner/courses')
.header({
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "authorization": token
})
.query("pageNumber", "1")
.query("sortDirection", "ASC")
.query("status", "all")
.end(function (response) {
     response.status.should.be.equal(200);
});
```

This is the documentation

```
unirest
 .post('http://mockbin.com/request')
 .query('name=nijiko')
 .query({
    pet: 'spot'
  })
 .then((response) => {
    console.log(response.body)
 });
```

You can try this version

Comment: thanks @Suryapratap Singh for the answer. i tried your solution but still get the error "TypeError: unirest(...).header(...).query is not a function". then i study the link you mentioned and reached the solution. so i just pass the parameter object to .qs() and it works. thanks

Comment: is it `header` or `headers` when passing multiple headers?